# How to execute JavaScript in PHP and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a PHP code and I use some JavaScript code inside just for alerting some text and a variable that I defined inside my PHP code.

How can I use my PHP variable in my JavaScript code to display it with an alert?

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$a="Jhon";
$b=true;
if($b)
{
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
     alert('Hello'.$jhon);
</script>
";
}
?>
```

Comment: Should work except for an error with a `'` mark -> `alert('Hello $jhon');` - you're already using a double-quoted string so you don't need to put the concatenation in it; that's just breaking the embedded JS (view source would show: `alert('Hello'Jhon);` ... actually the variable in PHP is `$a` so replace all instances of `$jhon` with `$a` as well

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  $a="Jhon";
  $b=true;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     if(<?php echo $b; ?>){
       alert('Hello<?php echo $b; ?>');
     }
</script>
```

Comment: The variable is called `$a` not `$jhon`

Comment: This will break if `$a` contains a new line or `'` character.

Comment: Why the condition in JS?

Comment: Why are you escaping `type=`?

Comment: @D.Pardal This is an example of passing PHP variable to Javascript and usage. PHP adds condition inside if statement and then js is using this value.

Comment: I get it, but why don't you do the condicion with PHP intsead of with JS, like in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap alert to function and call it at onload for example:

```
<?php 
$a="Jhon";
$b=true;
if($b)
{
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function callAlert(){
     alert('Hello$a');
     }
</script>
";
}
?>
<body onload="callAlert()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript operator for joining strings is `+`, not `.`. Also, `$a` needs to be in quotes, since otherwise JS will think that the value of `$a` is an identifier. Try this:

```
echo "
<script>
    alert('Hello, ' + '$a')
</script>
";
```

Also, what is `$jhon`?

Comment: Doesn't need the concatenation at all - it's just a PHP variable in a string so `alert('Hello {$a}');` should do it.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do that:
One:

```
<?php
$a="Jhon";
$b=true;
if($b){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello <?=$a?>');
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Two:

```
<?php
$a="Jhon";
$b=true;

if($b):?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello <?=$a?>');
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

I can give you more if you want
I hope this will help

Comment: Both these options are unsafe and will break if `$a` contains `'` or a new line character.

Comment: One more thing, to use php short tags, they must be enabled, otherwise use alert('Hello <?php echo $a; ?>');

Comment: No. `<?=` is always enabled and is not related to the `short_tags` directive which only covers `<?`.

Comment: php code or any code gets broken for any some characters, the question is not about how to make characters safe. Please use proper function to encode or decode text if breaks. Of course it will break if we put garbage

Comment: @Quentin please read question or comments carefully, otherwise you're giving wrong comments. Comments about short_tags were given additional to my answer, not to your comments.

Comment: Short_tags are not always enabled, your comments are wrong.

Comment: "Comments about short_tags were given additional to my answer, not to your comments" — The comment was still wrong.

Comment: "Short_tags are not always enabled, your comments are wrong" — While it is true that short_tags are not always enabled, `<?=` is not a short tag ([unless you are using PHP 5.3 or earlier](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)…in which case **you have major security risks and should upgrade now**).

Comment: This is exactly short_tags, where needs to be changed short_open_tag = on

Comment: No. `<?` is a short tag. `<?=` is not. [See the documentation I already linked to](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: You are wrong, please don't put misleading comments.

Comment: I've linked to supporting documentation in the PHP manual. Please stop accusing me of being wrong without providing a more authoritative source.

Comment: Please read the documentation that you provided, <? and <?= both short_tags, please read it for php versions too. If the question doesn't indicate version, we have to provide all approaches for different versions. Thank you

Comment: See my earlier comment regarding versions **where I already pointed out that `<?=` was covered by `short_open_tag` in ancient history**. PHP 5.3 has been end of life for **years**. It is dead. It is a security risk. Nobody should be using it. If anybody is, then they have bigger problems then the short_tags setting. In any **supported** version of PHP, `<?=` is not covered by `short_open_tags`.